# MongoDB Sort Method Not Found

Tags: java, mongodb, sorting, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am in the process of evaluating MongoDb and have come across a stumbling block which I have been unable to resolve. I am using the Mongo Java Driver 2.11.3.

When I run the following code using the Mongo Shell. I get the expected results.

```
db.people.find().sort({Counter: -1}).limit(10)
```

When I run from my application using the following code, I get an error which says "The sort method was not found."

```
<cfscript>
results = people.find().sort({Counter: -1}).limit(10).toArray();
</cfscript>
```

If I run this I get no error:

```
<cfscript>
results = people.find().limit(10).toArray();
</cfscript>
```

If I run this I get error - Sort Method was not found.

```
<cfscript>
results = people.find().sort({Counter: -1}).toArray();
</cfscript>
```

So after receiving this error I had a look at the driver api docs at: http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.11.3/ and according to what I can see, the `DBCursor` class contains both the `limit()` and `Sort()` methods yet the limit method seems to work fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update from comments:**

When I try and run the suggested code, I get an error that essentially says that it can't find the BasicDBObject Interface.

```
<cfscript> 
    myCollection = myDb.getCollection("people"); 
    sortedCursor = myCollection.find().sort(new BasicDBObject("Counter",1)).toArray(); 
    peopleResult = sortedCursor; 
</cfscript>
```

Comment: From the API it looks like you have to pass a DBObject to sort. Try: results = people.find().sort(new BasicDBObject("Counter",-1)).limit(10).toArray();

Comment: When I try to run the above code I get "Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface BasicDBObject."

Comment: @user3149617 - You cannot use `new` to create a java object in CF. It is only for components. Instead, use `createObject` along with the psuedo-constructor `init()`. See my comments below for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the java driver, the various find methods on your collection return a DBCursor, which in turn supports a sort method:
in [DBCollection](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.11.3/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html)

> DBCursor  find(DBObject ref)

in [DBCursor](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.11.3/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html)

> DBCursor  sort(DBObject orderBy)

So the whole thing together will look something like

```
DBCollection collection = ... // get collection
DBObject query = ... 
DBCursor sortedCursor = collection.find(query).sort(new BasicDBObject("fieldToSortBy",1));
```

Comment: When I try and run this code I get an error that essentially says that it can't find the BasicDBObject Interface.              <cfscript>
myCollection = myDb.getCollection("people");
sortedCursor = myCollection.find().sort(new BasicDBObject("Counter",1)).toArray();
peopleResult = sortedCursor;
</cfscript>

Comment: Well, I"m not sure what "cfscript" is, but since you're saying you're using the java driver, you should understand how java uses imports. I gave you a link to the API documentation above, you should just import the BasicDBObject class.

Comment: @user3149617 - Remember it is a java class, so you need to translate Steve's *java* example into the CF equivalent. Instead of `new` use the psuedo-constructor `init()` to create an instance of BasicDBObject. More specifically, create the instance with: `yourInstance = createObject("java", "com.mongodb.BasicDBObject").init("Counter", 1);` Then pass `yourInstance` into the `sort(...)` method.

Comment: Thanks Leigh and Steve for the help I did finally get it figured out with your help. In reference to what Leigh said, yes you were absolutely right, not sure why I didn't catch that but nonetheless. This is what I came up with and it works as expected....code below. One thing of note is that I did however run into an additional issue when running my code. I got this weird index error "Attempting to use index type '-1' where index types are not allowed (1 or -1 only)." But I was able to resolve that issue. Thanks again!

Comment: <cfscript>
 myDb = MongoC.getDB('test');
 collection = myDb.getCollection("people");
 mySortInstance = createObject("java", "com.mongodb.BasicDBObject").init("Counter", 1);
 myParseInstance = CreateObject("java","com.mongodb.util.JSON").parse(SerializeJSON(mySortInstance)); 
 cursor = collection.find().sort(myParseInstance).toArray();
 peopleResult = cursor;
</cfscript>

Comment: @user3149617 - Heh, no worries. It happens when switching back and forth between languages. Out of curiosity, which line caused the " "Attempting to use index type '-1..." error? BTW, you should post the final CF code as a separate "answer", so it is more visible to others. You can still mark Steve's response as the official answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using Steve's suggestion, this is my final code and it works as expected. One thing of note is that I did however run into an additional issue when running my code. I got this weird index error "Attempting to use index type '-1' where index types are not allowed (1 or -1 only)." But I was able to resolve that issue. Thanks again!

```
<cfscript>
function checkJson(x){
    variables.result = "";      
    if(IsJson(x)){
        variables.result = CreateObject("java","com.mongodb.util.JSON").parse(arguments.x);     
    }else{          
        variables.result = CreateObject("java","com.mongodb.util.JSON").parse(SerializeJSON(arguments.x));      
    }           
    return variables.result;
}
</cfscript>

<cfscript>
    myDb = MongoC.getDB('MFMFMF');
    collection = myDb.getCollection("people");
    mySortInstance = createObject("java", "com.mongodb.BasicDBObject").init("Counter", 1);  
    myParseInstance = checkJson(mySortInstance);
    cursor = collection.find().sort(myParseInstance).toArray();
    peopleResult = cursor;
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the final code. One note, within your UDF you should declare the variable in  `var` or `Local` scope, rather than the shared `variables` scope. That ensures the value cannot be modified from outside the function.